# I have 8 vertices of a box on a 3D terrain, and i need to seperate the box to a few smaller ones

Tags: python, python-3.x

For this problem, I got the 8 vertices of a box that i need to shrink, with a given size that is an integer which I need to shrink every side with. For example, if the size of the box I need to shrink is 8*8*8 and the shrinking size is 2, I need to return a list of all the vertices of the 4*4*4 boxes that fill the big box in a 3D coordinate system.

I thought about having a for loop that runs in range of the size of the box, but than I thought if I want to eventually seperate the box into a lot more boxes that are smaller and I want to fill the big box i would have to write an amount of code that I wouldn't be able to write. How to get this list of vertices without writing this much code?

Comment: what code did you try?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please give a concrete example of an input (are these lists, tuples, numbers, sets?) and the expected output for it, and include your attempts so far and the specific issues that you are facing. For example, indicate how you would go about writing that loop that you mention. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "an amount of code that I wouldn't be able to write", or "this much code".

Comment: This could probably be handled by sub-dividing the boxes recursively — but without further information about the input or sample code it's impossible to determine. Please [edit] your question and provide these missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using numpy, which allows easy bloc manipulation.

First I choose to represent a cube with an origin and three vectors : the unit cube is represented with `orig=np.array([0,0,0])` and `vects=np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])`.

Now a numpy function to generate the eight vertices:

```
import numpy as np

def cube(origin,edges):
    for e in edges:
        origin = np.vstack((origin,origin+e))
    return origin


cube(orig,vects)

array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Then an other to span minicubes in 3D :

```
def split(origin,edges,k):
    minicube=cube(origin,edges/k)
    for e in edges/k:
        minicube =np.vstack([minicube + i*e for i in range(k) ])
    return minicube.reshape(k**3,8,3) 


split (orig,vects,2)

array([[[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5]],
   ...

       [[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  1. ,  0.5],
        [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.5],
        [ 0.5,  0.5,  1. ],
        [ 1. ,  0.5,  1. ],
        [ 0.5,  1. ,  1. ],
        [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ]]])
```

Comment: When I ran your solution, I only got 8 entries. I think your algorithm only returns the diagonal values from orig to vects.

Comment: thank you very much!!! 1 more thing, can you explain to me why it only works when you do np.array to it and you cant put the value in without it?

Comment: That's numpy.  A+B is like a sum of vectors with arrays. with lists , it is concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here is a simple way to compute vertices in a grid with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

def make_grid(x_size, y_size, z_size, shrink_factor):
    n = (shrink_factor + 1) * 1j
    xx, yy, zz = np.mgrid[:x_size:n, :y_size:n, :z_size:n]
    return np.stack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel(), zz.ravel()], axis=1)

print(make_grid(8, 8, 8, 2))
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 4.]
 [0. 0. 8.]
 [0. 4. 0.]
 [0. 4. 4.]
 [0. 4. 8.]
 [0. 8. 0.]
 [0. 8. 4.]
 [0. 8. 8.]
 [4. 0. 0.]
 [4. 0. 4.]
 [4. 0. 8.]
 [4. 4. 0.]
 [4. 4. 4.]
 [4. 4. 8.]
 [4. 8. 0.]
 [4. 8. 4.]
 [4. 8. 8.]
 [8. 0. 0.]
 [8. 0. 4.]
 [8. 0. 8.]
 [8. 4. 0.]
 [8. 4. 4.]
 [8. 4. 8.]
 [8. 8. 0.]
 [8. 8. 4.]
 [8. 8. 8.]]
```

Otherwise with [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import product

def make_grid(x_size, y_size, z_size, shrink_factor):
    return [(x * x_size, y * y_size, z * z_size)
            for x, y, z in product((i / shrink_factor
                                    for i in range(shrink_factor + 1)), repeat=3)]

print(*make_grid(8, 8, 8, 2), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 8.0)
(0.0, 4.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 4.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 4.0, 8.0)
(0.0, 8.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 8.0, 4.0)
(0.0, 8.0, 8.0)
(4.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(4.0, 0.0, 4.0)
(4.0, 0.0, 8.0)
(4.0, 4.0, 0.0)
(4.0, 4.0, 4.0)
(4.0, 4.0, 8.0)
(4.0, 8.0, 0.0)
(4.0, 8.0, 4.0)
(4.0, 8.0, 8.0)
(8.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(8.0, 0.0, 4.0)
(8.0, 0.0, 8.0)
(8.0, 4.0, 0.0)
(8.0, 4.0, 4.0)
(8.0, 4.0, 8.0)
(8.0, 8.0, 0.0)
(8.0, 8.0, 4.0)
(8.0, 8.0, 8.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

My example below will work on a generic box and assumes integer coordinates.

```
    import numpy as np

    def create_cube(start_x, start_y, start_z, size):
        return np.array([
            [x,y,z]
            for z in [start_z, start_z+size]        
            for y in [start_y, start_y+size]
            for x in [start_x, start_x+size]
        ])

    def subdivide(box, scale):
        start =  np.min(box, axis=0)
        end = np.max(box, axis=0) - scale

        return np.array([
            create_cube(x, y, z, scale)
            for z in range(start[2], end[2]+1)
            for y in range(start[1], end[1]+1)
            for x in range(start[0], end[0]+1)
        ])

    cube = create_cube(1, 3, 2, 8)
```

Cube will look like:

```
    array([[ 1,  3,  2],
           [ 9,  3,  2],
           [ 1, 11,  2],
           [ 9, 11,  2],
           [ 1,  3, 10],
           [ 9,  3, 10],
           [ 1, 11, 10],
           [ 9, 11, 10]])
```

Running the following subdivide:

```
    subcubes = subdivide(cube, 2)
```

The subdivide function creates an nparray with a shape: (343, 8, 3). You would expect to have 343 subcubes moving the 2x2 cube evenly over an 8x8 cube.

Comment: thanks, but i need it to work on boxes and not only cubes such as a 4*6*7 box